# Pentaho | kjb file stuck

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-design-studio

I am working in Pentaho DI spoon tool.
I have created one KJB job with many transformations.
I have click on run button ini KJB  file but it is not showing any response. I think it is not even started. Where should I see logs? What should be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a job using spoon you get the logging window in bottom screen.make sure when you run you change log level from 'basic' to 'detailed'

if you still cant work may be the processes required more memory to work

step1. go to C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration

step2. right click and edit spoon.bat file

step3. verify settings as -Xmx2048m

if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"

step 4. save and restart spoon and then try executing your job